# Question about a completeness relation in Peskin Chapter 7: radiative corrections p. 212 equation 7.2

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, renormalization, correlation-functions

In P&S book, in Charpter 7: radiative corrections p. 212 （attached beneath, the completeness relation: (Equation 7.2)
$$\textbf{1}=\left\vert \Omega\right\rangle\left\langle\Omega\right\vert+\sum\limits_{\lambda}\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_\textbf{p}} \left\vert \textbf{p}\right\rangle\left\langle\textbf{p}\right\vert.\tag{7.2}$$
This is in analogy with Equation 7.1:
$$(\textbf{1})_{1-particle}=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_\textbf{p}} \left\vert \textbf{p}\right\rangle\left\langle\textbf{p}\right\vert.\tag{7.1}$$
My question is:what exactly $\sum\limits_{\lambda}$ mean? P&S say: "the sum runs over all zero-momentum states $\left\vert \textbf{p}\right\rangle\\$. I don't really get this, does this mean we use $\lambda$ to denote different particles that are present in scattering processes? Such as: $\lambda=1$ denotes electron and $\lambda=2$ denotes positron?

The original Page 212 of P&S book:

[image]

Comment: @Andrew Thanks! I just fix this, sorry about the mess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\lambda_0\rangle$ runs over all the single particle states at zero momentum. This will encode spin degrees of freedom -- so for a spin-1/2 particle, you'd sum over $m=1/2$ and $m=-1/2$ states, where $m$ is the spin quantum number (as well as antiparticle states).

Comment: $\lambda_0$ also runs over states with more than two particles. $P$ denotes total momentum of the system.